# How do I get a TPM module for a motherboard that does not already have one?

Tags: motherboard, bitlocker, tpm

I have an ASUS P8P67 DELUXE motherboard, which (as far as I can tell) does not come with a TPM module, so I can't use BitLocker without a PIN or USB key.

Is there any way to buy and install a TPM module myself?

Comment: I don't think so, since TPM is also part of the bios.

Comment: Where would you "install" it to?  :\  Just get a USB/Bluetooth/PCIe one if you can.

Comment: `How do I get a TPM module for a motherboard that does not already have one?` Wait, you **want(ed)** one‽ ಠ_ఠ I remember back when people were calling the TPM the “devil’s tool to control your system”. But seriously, what about just using a third-party encryption tool like TrueCrypt; was that an option?

Comment: @Synetech That's what I ended up doing (this was a year ago). I just wanted the convenience of not having to type a password at boot. Btw, nice interrobang you got there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some ASUS enthusiast motherboards do have a slot into which you can plug a TPM module (which ASUS sells separately). Unfortunately the P8P67 DELUXE is not one of them.

If you're merely trying to enable BitLocker on Windows 7 or Windows 8, you can do that by setting up a [local group policy to allow BitLocker without a TPM](https://superuser.com/q/288429/144961).

Comment: Hm, that is unfortunate; I was hoping there was some secret TPM slot on my board. Too bad TPMs don't just fit in PCI slots (any idea why they don't make them like that?). Thanks.

Comment: @grantman16 TPM doesn't need the performance of the PCI bus.  Instead (along with the bios, fan controllers, and legacy ports like ps2/com/lpt) it's connected to the much simpler LPC bus which is a derivative of the ISA bus designed for the original IBM PC over 30 years ago.  Unfortunately non-corporate/government interest in full system crypto has never reached a level sufficient to make a product with a pcie bridge chip.

Comment: It's also on the LPC bus so it's accessible to the BIOS with no drivers or intermediary devices whatsoever.  This way the BIOS can measure itself and possibly a bootloader in order to implement things like SecureBoot.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on if your motherboard can handle the installation of a TPM chip such as the AXXTPME5 by Intel. Or a TPM module using 20 pin headers, for example. You will need to check the specifics on your motherboard.

Portable TPM modules are, AFAIK, a thing of theory and not mass production. If your MoBo doesn't have support for it, then you're practically out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I found my TPM module from Quiet PC.com in the UK. They had what I needed for the Gigabyte motherboard that is my pc, cost about 36.00 shipped to me in the US. If you know your motherboard manufacturer go their website and do the search typing in TPM module. I have the manual that came with the Gigabyte board which showed where it plugged into on the motherboard and then just had to enable it through the BIOS which it is embedded to make it difficult to find, but it is there, you just have to do some searching.