# Windows 10: Bitlocker without TPM

Tags: windows, encryption

I have an Asus K55A laptop without a TPM. For over a year, I had Windows 8.1 installed and Bitlocker was enabled requiring a password at startup. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 Enterprise (clean install) and cannot enable Bitlocker on my operation system drive.

The thing is, I have enabled "Require additional authentication at startup" in the local group policy, as described in [this previous superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/288429/how-to-enable-bitlocker-without-tpm).

I have forced gpupdate, restarted my computer...nothing is working. What am I missing? Is this a bug in Windows 10 or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, my laptop is joined to a domain. When I got into work, and was actively connected to the domain, Bitlocker was able to initialize and start. Seems odd that I had to be actively connected to the domain. I didn't have this issue when I initialized Bitlocker for Windows 8.

Comment: There is a group policy regarding bitlocker.  The policy specifies whether or not the TPM key has to be able to be backed up to AD (Active Directory) domain controller.  Not being able to back up a key forces it to not work.  I wonder if it has to do with that?  You may want to check your group policy editor for "local computer" and see?